# How do I create a new column that references other row's data for its values?

Tags: python, dataframe, date, stock

I have the following data frame:

|  | Month | Day | Year | Open | High | Low | Close | Week |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 1 | 2003 | 46.593 | 46.656 | 46.405 | 46.468 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | 2003 | 46.538 | 46.66 | 46.47 | 46.673 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 3 | 2003 | 46.717 | 46.781 | 46.53 | 46.750 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 | 4 | 2003 | 46.815 | 46.843 | 46.68 | 46.750 | 1 |
| 4 | 1 | 5 | 2003 | 46.935 | 47.000 | 46.56 | 46.593 | 1 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 7257 | 10 | 26 | 2022 | 381.619 | 387.5799 | 381.350 | 382.019 | 43 |
| 7258 | 10 | 27 | 2022 | 383.07 | 385.00 | 379.329 | 379.98 | 43 |
| 7259 | 10 | 28 | 2022 | 379.869 | 389.519 | 379.67 | 389.019 | 43 |
| 7260 | 10 | 31 | 2022 | 386.44 | 388.399 | 385.26 | 386.209 | 44 |
| 7261 | 11 | 1 | 2022 | 390.14 | 390.39 | 383.29 | 384.519 | 44 |

I want to create a new column titled 'week high' which will reference each week every year and pull in the high.  So for Week 1, Year 2003, it will take the Highest High from rows 0 to 4 but for Week 43, Year 2022, it will take the Highest High from rows 7257 to 7259.

Is it possible to reference the columns Week and Year to calculate that value?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas), create a weekly period and use it as grouper for `transform('max')`:

```
group = pd.to_datetime(df[['Year', 'Month', 'Day']]).dt.to_period('W')
# or, if you already have a "Week" column
# group = "Week"


df['week_high'] = df.groupby(group)['High'].transform('max')
```

Output:

```
      Month  Day  Year     Open      High      Low    Close  Week  week_high
0         1    1  2003   46.593   46.6560   46.405   46.468   1.0     47.000
1         1    2  2003   46.538   46.6600   46.470   46.673   1.0     47.000
2         1    3  2003   46.717   46.7810   46.530   46.750   1.0     47.000
3         1    4  2003   46.815   46.8430   46.680   46.750   1.0     47.000
4         1    5  2003   46.935   47.0000   46.560   46.593   1.0     47.000
7257     10   26  2022  381.619  387.5799  381.350  382.019  43.0    389.519
7258     10   27  2022  383.070  385.0000  379.329  379.980  43.0    389.519
7259     10   28  2022  379.869  389.5190  379.670  389.019  43.0    389.519
7260     10   31  2022  386.440  388.3990  385.260  386.209  44.0    390.390
7261     11    1  2022  390.140  390.3900  383.290  384.519    44    390.390
```

Comment: Sorry, to piggie back off of that question, How would I reference the final close figure for the week to create a new column of just the prior week's close?

Comment: I was able to get it by using the following!
wclose = pd.to_datetime(SPY[['Year','Month','Day']]).dt.to_period('W')
SPY['Week_Close'] = SPY.groupby(wclose)['Close'].transform('last')

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are using pandas. Other libraries will work similar.

Create a new DataFrame aggregated per week using `groupby` and join it back to your original DataFrame

```py
df_grouped = df["Week", "High"].groupby("Week").max().rename(columns={"High":"Highest High"}
df_result = df.join(df_grouped, "Week")
```